# src.rpm and rpm files extract and compress

Tags: centos, rpm

**i download this file util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.src.rpm**

> and i extract all files on it using this command

```
 rpm2cpio ./util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

> this is all files extracted

```
[root@vps8865 SPECS]# ls
0060-build-sys-add-CFLAGS-and-LDFLAGS-for-daemons-and-sha.patch
0061-libmount-be-more-restrictive-about-valid-tag-names.patch
0062-mount-umount-swapon-fsck-lsblk-findmnt-ignore-malfor.patch
0063-login-mount-fix-__SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX-usage.patch
0064-bash-completion-use-n-as-IFS-when-ask-for-filenames.patch
0065-hwclock-change-audit-message.patch
0066-su-clean-up-groups-initialization.patch
0067-lscpu-Fix-model-and-model-name-on-Power-Systems.patch
0068-lscpu-use-cpu-and-revision-tag-if-available.patch
0069-findfs-add-ability-to-work-with-PART-UUID-LABEL-too.patch
0070-libblkid-fix-memory-leak-in-blkid_parse_tag_string.patch
0071-findmnt-don-t-rely-on-st_dev-for-target.patch
0072-libmount-cleanup-fs-root-detection-code.patch
0073-libmount-mark-overlay-as-pseudo-FS.patch
0074-logger-be-more-precise-about-port-description.patch
0075-libfdisk-gpt-be-more-careful-with-64bit-constants.patch
0076-lsns-backport-new-command.patch
0077-lib-strutils-make-strmode-more-generic.patch
0078-lsipc-backport-new-command.patch
0079-blkdiscard-backport-zeroout-support.patch
0080-sulogin-and-agetty-virtual-consoles-support-xvc-and-.patch
0081-chrt-backport-DEADLINE-scheduler-support.patch
0082-fdisk-backport-DOS-logical-partitions-chain-reorder.patch
0083-tests-cleanup-tests.patch
0084-libmount-add-support-for-bind-ro.patch
0085-libblkid-store-only-canonical-devnames-to-the-cache.patch
0086-libblkid-avoid-recursion-in-EBR.patch
0087-findmnt-fix-target-behaviour.patch
0088-su-properly-clear-child-PID.patch
0089-fdisk-fix-Blocks-column-calculation.patch
0090-fdisk-fix-menu-for-GPT.patch
0091-logger-backport-size.patch
0092-fdisk-print-header-UUID-for-GPT.patch
0093-fdisk-improve-l-error-handling.patch
0094-losetup-improve-man-page-SYNOPSIS.patch
0095-libblkid-fix-potential-bufer-overflows.patch
0096-umount-fix-obsolete-info-about-loop-in-umount.8.patch
0097-mount-fix-all-and-nofail-return-code.patch
0098-umount-exclude-selinuxfs-from-all.patch
0099-sfdisk-remove-useless-CDROM-detection-for-s.patch
0100-more-fix-repeat-search-crash.patch
0101-more-avoid-double-free-on-exit.patch
0102-ipcs-show-gid-instead-of-uid.patch
0103-ipcs-fix-JP-status-message.patch
0104-swapon-fix-discard-option-parsing.patch
0105-fallocate-Added-posix_fallocate-support.patch
0106-zramctl-backport-from-v2.29.patch
0107-libblkid-zfs-let-s-keep-compiler-happy.patch
0108-blkid-make-zfs-detection-more-robust.patch
0109-zfs-make-less-syscalls.patch
0110-libblkid-zfs-keep-bufferes-read-only.patch
0111-libblkid-don-t-mark-zfs-as-RAID.patch
0112-tests-update-ZFS-test.patch
0113-libblkid-zfs-add-cast-to-fix-UB-cppcheck.patch
0114-libblkid-Avoid-OOB-access-on-illegal-ZFS-superblocks.patch
0115-lscpu-backport-from-v2.29.patch
0116-fdisk-use-sysfs_devno_is_wholedisk.patch
0117-zramctl-add-bash-completion.patch
0118-zramctl-make-mm_stat-parser-more-robust.patch
0119-fdisk-improve-menu-and-u-for-GPT.patch
0120-tests-update-for-RHEL7.4-changes.patch
0121-zramctl-be-more-specific-about-default-output.patch
0122-libfdisk-gpt-fix-UUID-printing.patch
0123-libblkid-Add-metadata-signature-check-for-IMSM-on-4K.patch
0124-lscpu-use-sysfs-for-table-access-if-available.patch
0125-lscpu-improve-for-offline-CPUs-on-AMD.patch
0126-libmount-use-eacess-rather-than-open-to-check-mtab-u.patch
0127-agetty-fix-etc-os-release-parsing.patch
0128-fdisk-remove-obsolete-info-about-GPT-from-man-page.patch
0129-libfdisk-gpt-sync-type-UUIDs-with-upstream.patch
0130-lscpu-cleanup-DMI-detection-return-codes.patch
0131-flock-zero-timeout-is-valid.patch
0132-logger-add-man-page-note-about-the-default-tag.patch
0133-script-use-all-io-to-write.patch
0134-logger-do-not-rely-only-getlogin-3-telling-who-ran-t.patch
0135-login-use-IPv4-on-IPv4-mapping-to-IPv6.patch
0136-blkid-update-man-page-about-lsblk-and-ambivalent-pro.patch
0137-wipefs-fix-t-filter.patch
0138-tests-backport-new-ts_scsi_debug_init.patch
0139-tests-ts_scsi_debug_init-must-not-run-in-a-subshell.patch
0140-tests-cleanup-fdisk-outputs.patch
0141-tests-check-for-mdadm.patch
0142-lsmem-chmem-backport-new-commands.patch
0143-lsmem-make-split-optional-follow-output-by-default.patch
0144-libmount-fix-access-utab-write-test.patch
0145-login-add-LOGIN_PLAIN_PROMPT-to-login.defs.patch
0146-libblkid-Add-VDO-superblock-information-into-blkid.patch
0147-include-debug-don-t-print-pointer-address-for-SUID-p.patch
0148-mkswap-tolerate-ENOTSUP-when-failing-to-relabel.patch
0149-libmount-fix-debug-message.patch
0150-lsns-missing-ns-name-is-not-error.patch
0151-lsns-Fix-parser-for-proc-pid-stat-which-is-including.patch
0152-libsmartcols-add-basic-tools-necessary-for-new-versi.patch
0153-libsmartcols-backport-upstream-version-v2.32-158-gc0.patch
0154-tests-backport-libsmartcols-tests.patch
0155-lslogins-fix-password-verification.patch
0156-umount-add-note-about-lazy.patch
0157-losetup-add-info-about-lazy-detach-to-manpage.patch
0158-setarch-Fix-ppc64le-architectures.patch
0159-fallocate-backport-v2.32-164-g641af90dc.patch
0160-libmount-fix-mnt_table_is_fs_mounted-for-rbind.patch
0161-mount-add-ext4-to-some-places-in-man-page.patch
0162-agetty-keep-c_iflags-unmodified-on-autologin.patch
0163-sulogin-don-t-use-strcpy-enlarge-pwd-line-buffer.patch
0164-sulogin-improve-support-for-locked-root-account.patch
0165-sulogin-Always-make-echo-work-after-performing-getpa.patch
0166-sulogin-make-getpasswd-.-return-NULL-on-D.patch
0167-sulogin-bail-out-from-getpasswd-.-on-timeout.patch
0168-losetup-keep-f-and-devname-mutually-exclusive.patch
0169-lscpu-fix-mzx-min-MHz-reporting.patch
0170-chcpu-cleanup-return-codes.patch
0171-chcpu-cleanup-stdout-stderr-usage.patch
0172-lscpu-chcpu-Avoid-use-of-the-old-CPU-macros.patch
0173-chcpu-Fix-maximal-number-of-CPUs.patch
0174-libblkid-minix-Match-minix-superblock-types.patch
0175-libblkid-minix-Sanity-check-superblock-s_state-for-v.patch
0176-libblkid-minix-Use-same-checks-for-version-3.patch
0177-mount-append-inverting-options-for-mount.-type-on-us.patch
0178-sulogin-backport-RHEL-8-version.patch
0179-agetty-backport-RHEL-8-version.patch
0180-swapon-mkswap-sync-man-page-with-upstream.patch
0181-libblkid-zeroize-errno-on-blkid_probe_get_buffer-suc.patch
0182-libmount-fix-mount-a-for-cifs.patch
0183-agetty-fix-man-page-formatting.patch
0184-build-sys-add-missing-open_memstream-test.patch
0185-lib-canonicalize-make-DM-canonicalization-more-robus.patch
0186-libblkid-fix-file-descriptor-leak-in-blkid_verify.patch
0187-misc-cleanup-size_t-vs.-int-for-string_add_to_idarra.patch
0188-setarch-use-personality-system-call-when-it-is-avail.patch
0189-setarch-fix-personality-syscall-return-code-check.patch
0190-build-sys-check-for-librtas.patch
0191-setarch-prefer-preprocessor-rather-than-autotools-ch.patch
0192-libmount-Preserve-empty-string-value-in-optstr-parsi.patch
0193-tests-accept-empty-values.patch
0194-liblkid-Add-length-check-in-probe_nilfs2-before-crc3.patch
0195-libmount-fix-is-mounted-check-for-btrfs.patch
0196-libmount-fix-uid-and-gid-translation.patch
0197-col-make-flush_line-a-little-bit-robust.patch
0198-libmount-fix-mount-a-EBUSY-for-cifs.patch
0199-chrt-follow-nice-setting-prefer-sched_setscheduler.patch
0200-chrt-default-to-SCHED_RR-policy.patch
0201-chrt-use-SCHED_FLAG_RESET_ON_FORK-for-sched_setattr.patch
2.17-kill-strtol.patch
2.23-login-lastlog-create.patch
2.24-agetty-clocal.patch
2.24-agetty-etc-os-release.patch
2.24-blockdev-setbsz-hint.patch
2.24-fsck-fstab.patch
2.24-libfdisk-fix-SIGFPE.patch
2.24-libmount-3.14.patch
2.24-libmount-canonicalize-for-conversion-from-loopdev.patch
2.24-libmount-mem.patch
2.24-losetup-add-device.patch
2.24-losetup-offset.patch
2.24-partx-update.patch
2.24-sfdisk-y-n-miscmatch.patch
2.24-su-fix-lastlog-and-btmp-logging.patch
2.24-su-suppress-PAM-info-messages.patch
2.24-tests-portability.patch
2.24-unshare-mount-fork.patch
2.24-utmpdump-ipv6.patch
2.25-blockdev-geom.patch
2.25-dmesg-w.patch
2.25-flock-nfs4.patch
2.25-fsck-nohelper.patch
2.25-fstrim-all.patch
2.25-hwclock-hang.patch
2.25-lib-add-path_strdup.patch
2.25-libblkid-detect-alone-PMBR.patch
2.25-libblkid-gpt-512.patch
2.25-libblkid-Identify-extN-file-system-properly.patch
2.25-libblkid-io-errors.patch
2.25-libblkid-no-more-probe-for-btrfs-backup-superblock.patch
2.25-libblkid-return-codes.patch
2.25-libblkid-thinpool.patch
2.25-libblkid-xfs-log.patch
2.25-libblkid-xfs.patch
2.25-lscpu-discontinuous-NUMA-nodes.patch
2.25-lscpu-d_type.patch
2.25-lscpu-sort-NUMA.patch
2.25-mount-man-default.patch
2.25-mount-man-xfs.patch
2.25-swapon-discard.patch
2.25-taskset-man-fix-permissions.patch
2.25-uuidd-timeout.patch
2.25-wipefs-call-BLKRRPART-when-erase-partition-table.patch
2.25-wipefs-nested-pt.patch
2.26-blkdiscard.patch
2.26-libblkid-fat.patch
2.26-libsmartcols.patch
2.26-logger-man-kern.patch
2.26-login-SIGXFSZ.patch
2.26-lsblk-mpath.patch
2.26-lslogins.patch
2.26-mount-man-move.patch
2.26-raw-stat.patch
2.26-su-coredump-message.patch
2.26-unshare-rebase.patch
2.27-libblkid-xfs-log.patch
2.28-lslogins-rebase.patch
nologin.8
nologin.c
rhel7.0-unshare-user.patch
util-linux-2.23.2.tar.xz
util-linux-60-raw.rules
util-linux-chsh-chfn.pamd
util-linux-login.pamd
util-linux-remote.pamd
util-linux-runuser-l.pamd
util-linux-runuser.pamd
util-linux.spec
util-linux-su-l.pamd
util-linux-su.pamd
v2.26-nsenter-selinux.patch
```

> i have edit some files
>
> now i need help how compress all extracted file to rpm file . or
> src.rpm file
>
> So that I can reinstall the modified package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install rpmbuild to build rpm packages

```
yum install rpm-build
```

There is a directory SPECS upon extracting the source rpm. Use the spec file in there to rebuild the package like so

```
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/package.spec
```

Comment: [root@vps8865 SPECS]# rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/package.spec
error: failed to stat /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/package.spec: No such file or directory

Comment: that would be, where you extracted your package with the spec file's name. do not copy my command directly, change it accordingly

Comment: I have modified my question and added the files extracted from the package util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.src.rpm  package.spec file not found

Comment: there is only one spec file in that directory. util-linux.spec

Comment: Oh Thanks Thanks Thanks

Comment: I have no experience with what happened but I put my files in a folder /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES Then I executed the command rpmbuild -ba util-linux.spec Some operations happened It seems to have ended well But I don't know where to find the file my rpm

Comment: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS. Look carefully, there will be your new util-linux rpm file

Comment: You saved me from a problem I didn't know how to solve for days. Thank you